# PHP installed twice - get rid of one

Tags: php, centos

Newb question:
Running CentOS 5.x I had an older version of PHP (about 5.2.9 or something) and I downloaded the source for and installed the latest (5.2.17). Now, I checked yum and it had PHP 5.2.17 so I installed it. So now I have php installed by yum in /usr/bin and my old manual install in /usr/local/bin. I'm getting an exception 'pdo_mysql extension not installed' when I try to run php from the command line for some users and I think that the problem is that I have two PHPs running around. How can I get rid of the manually installed one?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

"make uninstall" in the source dir. If that doesn't work, bring out <kbd>rm</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

So, you've compiled and installed php from source, right? You may
yum remove php
and then make install from source php dir for sure, that all is right.

Comment: Thanks but for consistency I'd rather do everything the yum way. I forgot why we installed from source a few months ago, but now that yum has caught up I feel like it would be better to get rid of the manual install and keep the yum install.